# XML parsing throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have entered below code to file, but it throws `NullPointerException`. I am trying to parse resource.xml file using DOM parser. The first item is printed successfully, but it stucks in the second iteration.

```
package readXmlProject;

import org.w3c.dom.*;

import javax.xml.parsers.*;

import java.io.*;

public class readXml {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{

            Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse("resource.xml");
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();


        NodeList fieldsList = doc.getElementsByTagName("records").item(0).getChildNodes();
        System.out.println(fieldsList.getLength());
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldsList.getLength(); i++) {
            NodeList itemDetails = fieldsList.item(i).getChildNodes();
            for(int j=0;j<fieldsList.getLength();j++){
                System.out.println(itemDetails.item(j).getTextContent());
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    };
}
public static void getFieldsList(Document doc){
    NodeList fieldsList = doc.getElementsByTagName("fields").item(0).getChildNodes();

    for (int i = 0; i < fieldsList.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println(fieldsList.item(i).getNodeName()); 
    }
}
}
```

After executing the above code below is the output :

```
100
1
1438929000
'00851'
BNC SUVIDHA SPL
1
BBS 
BHUBANESWAR    
'00:00:00'
'22:50:00'
0
BBS 
BHUBANESWAR    
BNC 
BANGALORE CANT 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at readXmlProject.readXml.main(readXml.java:22)
```

According to above error, below line is causing the error

```
System.out.println(itemDetails.item(j).getTextContent());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for(int j=0;j<fieldsList.getLength();j++)` should be `for(int j=0;j< itemDetails.getLength();j++)`

Comment: It worked, but can you explain why it worked for first time but not second?

Comment: The number of elements are same as number of fields, then why did it fail if I used fieldsList.getLength()

Comment: it's failing randomly when there is more fields that items ? it's a trivial bug, you were iterating with the wrong iteration

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to change the inner loop.

`for(int j=0;j<fieldsList.item(i).getLength();j++){`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want to iterate over the items in the itemDetails list in the inner loop.  If so, the code for the inner loop should be

```
for(int j=0;j<itemDetails.getLength();j++){
```